# if a is algebraic over F, then how can we say OR can we say $a_o+a_1a+a_2a^2 +....a_na^n$ is algebraic over F

Tags: ring-theory

One intuitive proof which i think is 
a is algebraic over F $\implies F(a)$ is finite extension and thus algebraic extension which means all elements which are linear combinations of $a^i \forall i$ are algebraic and so $a_o+a_1a+a_2a^2 +....a_na^n$ is algebraic over F

keeping it aside
a is algebraic $\implies \exists f(x) \in F[x] : f(a) = 0 $ here $f(x) = b_o+b_1x+b_2x^2 + ....+b_nx^n$

Ideally for proving the above statement, how can we create such polynomial say h(x) and say that  $a_o+a_1a+a_2a^2 +....a_na^n$ is actual zero of h(x).

Comment: A direct proof of that is not trivial to find. For example, given a polynomial that has $x$ as a zero, and another with $y$ as a zero, finding one with $x+y$ as a zero is a non-trivial task that can be accomplished, for instance, using certain resultant between two polynomials

Comment: If you don't like [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), for some $b \in F[a]$, use a $F$-vector space isomorphism $F[a] \to F^d$ (where $d$ is the degree of $a$'s minimal polynomial) to obtain the matrix $B \in F^{d \times d}$ of the multiplication by $b$. Then $b$ is a root of $\det(B-x I)$ and the minimal polynomial of $b$ is the minimal polynomial of $B$.